# Как конвертировать символы unicodе в буквы русского алфавита

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть строка `"\u0410\u0410 1000 \u0410\u0410"`, это ответ с сервера. Мне нужно конвертировать ее, чтобы исходная срока имела вид: `АА 1000 АА`.
Пробовал использовать следующий код:

```
QString str = "\u0410\u0410 1000 \u0410\u0410";
QTextCodec *c = QTextCodec::codecForName("KOI8-U");
QString result = c->fromUnicode(str);
```

Но переменная `result` содержит то же самое что, и `str`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как раскодировать строку.

Ответ приходит такой:

```
[{"id":229,"creator":123,"name":"\u0421\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0‌440\u0438\u043a\u0418\u043c\u043f\u0440\u0435\u0437\u0430\u0413\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0430","hw_type":"granit_v6","hw_id‌​":"790090","phone":"‌​+375292775802","is_f‌ree":0,"type":"auto"‌​
```

И я пытаюсь получить имя на русском.

Comment: @jfs ответ приходит такой: [{"id":229,"creator":123,"name":"\u0421\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0440\u0438\u043a \u0418\u043c\u043f\u0440\u0435\u0437\u0430 \u0413\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0430","hw_type":"granit_v6","hw_id":"790090","phone":"+375292775802","is_free":0,"type":"auto". А я с него достаю уже то что мне нужно.

Comment: @jfs И я пытаюсь получить имя на русском.

Comment: это значит, что на входе `"\\u0410"` (слеш буквально во вводе есть). Используйте `QJsonDocument::fromJson`, чтобы распознать ввод. [How to create/read/write JSon files in Qt5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15893040/4279)

Comment: @jfs Спасибо. Это не много прояснило, но у меня все равно не получаеться. JsonDocument имеет значение NULL, QJsonObject также и в строку ничего не поступает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так.
 QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
 QJsonObject root = d.object();

 QJsonValue jv = root.value("name");
 QString str = jv.toString();

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от вашего окружения: `"\u0410"` уже равно `"А"` (от компилятора и [его опций зависит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662138/23044)).

В вашем случае, сервер вам [json-документ](http://json.org/) присылает, то есть к вам приходит `"\"\\u0410\""` (слеш заэкранирован).

> И я пытаюсь получить имя на русском.

Вот пример, как имя из приведённого json-документа достать:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonValue>

int main()
{
  QByteArray json_data = R"json(
[
  {
    "id": 229,
    "creator": 123,
    "name": "\u0421\u0443\u0431\u0430"
  }
]
)json";
  qDebug() << "json: " << json_data;
  QJsonDocument json_doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json_data);
  QJsonArray array = json_doc.array();
  for (const QJsonValue& v : array)
    qDebug() << "name: " << v.toObject()["name"].toString();
  return array.isEmpty();
}
```

Результат:

```
json:  "\n[\n  {\n    \"id\": 229,\n    \"creator\": 123,\n    \"name\": \"\\u0421\\u0443\\u0431\\u0430\"\n  }\n]\n"
name:  "Суба"
```

Видно, что русский текст успешно получен. [Пример кода, как json-документ, полученный по сети, распознать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661222/23044).