# Как пользоваться QJsonDocument

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите пожалуйста как пользоваться `QJsonDocument`. Я cделал запрос на сервер. Получаю ответ в таком формате: 
`[{"id":229,"creator":123,"name":"\u0421\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0440\u0438\u043a \u0418\u043c\u043f\u0440\u0435\u0437\u0430 \u0413\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0430"}, {"id":229,"creator":123,"name":"\u0421\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0440\u0438\u043a \u0418\u043c\u043f\u0440\u0435\u0437\u0430 \u0413\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0430"}]`

Это массив объектов.
Мне нужно вытащить из ответа: name. В поле `name` содержаться русские символы представлены символами юникода. В конечном итоге мне нужно получить  из ответа значение параметра `name` на русском языке.
Пробывал такой код, но он не работает, подскажите пожалуйста что не так:

```
QUrl url(urlStr);
QNetworkRequest request(url);

QEventLoop loop;
QNetworkAccessManager manager;

connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);
loop.exec();

QString data = reply->readAll();


QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
QJsonObject root = d.object();

QJsonValue jv = root.value("name");
QString str = jv.toString();
```

Comment: Вам сначала нужно документ разбить на JsonArray, а потом уже получать значение.

Comment: обратите внимание, что `reply->readAll()` всегда `""` (пустая строка) возвращает при повторном вызове здесь.

Comment: @Вячеслав Савченко Спасибо!

Comment: @jfs Огромное вам спасибо! Я с этим больше недели мучался. Спасибо вам.

Comment: @AlexNemet: если решение в ответе работает для вас, то чтобы это показать другим [вы можете "принять" ответ (галочка слева)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` обозначают массив в json-формате, поэтому следует [`.array()` метод](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#array) использовать, а не `.object()`:

```
QJsonArray array = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json_text).array();
for (const QJsonValue& v : array)
  qDebug() << "name: " << v.toObject()["name"].toString();
```

Полный пример (получить свой внешний ip c https://httpbin.org/ используя Qt):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  QNetworkAccessManager manager {&app};
  QObject::connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [&app] (QNetworkReply* reply) {
      if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        QByteArray json_data = reply->readAll();
        qDebug() << "json: " << json_data;
        QJsonDocument json_doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json_data);
        auto data = json_doc.object();
        qDebug() << "public ip: " << data["origin"].toString();
        app.quit();
      } else {
        qDebug() << "error: " << reply->error();
        app.exit(1);
      }
    });
  manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://httpbin.org/ip")));
  return app.exec();
}
```

Файл `read-json.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += c++11
QT += core
QT -= gui
QT += network
TARGET = read-json
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += read-json.cc
```

Чтобы собрать и запустить:

```
$ qmake && make && ./read-json
```

См. также [JSON Save Game Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html).