# Как парсить с Википедии в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, парсер, mediawiki

У меня есть класс для парсинга страниц под названием Loader:

loader.h

```
#ifndef LOADER_H
#define LOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class Loader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Loader(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void makeRequest(QString endPointRequest);
signals:
    void dataReadyRead(QByteArray);
public slots:
    void ReadRead(QNetworkReply *reply);
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *m_manager= new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
};

#endif // LOADER_H
```

loader.cpp

```
#include "loader.h"

Loader::Loader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(m_manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(ReadRead(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void Loader::makeRequest(QString endPointRequest)
{
    m_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(endPointRequest)));
}

void Loader::ReadRead(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QByteArray myData;
    myData = reply->readAll();
    emit dataReadyRead(myData);
}
```

И в основной форме я передаю ссылку для парсинга :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&theLoader,SIGNAL(dataReadyRead(QByteArray)),this,SLOT(dataUploaded(QByteArray)) );
}
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    theLoader.makeRequest("http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ключевая_ставка_в_России");
}

void MainWindow::dataUploaded(QByteArray data)
{
    QString dataString;
    dataString = data;
    ui->apiResponseDisplay->setText(dataString);
    qDebug()<<dataString;
}
```

Причём какую я бы ссылку не добавлял [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ключевая_ставка_в_России](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8), http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8&oldid=91903866, [http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ключевая_ставка_в_России&oldid=91903866](http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8&oldid=91903866)

Все равно возвращается пустая страница: "".
Как мне спарсить данные с Википедии?

Comment: Не следует парсить html, когда есть замечательный [API MediaWiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)

Comment: @vp_arth Я не совсем понимаю как с ним работать. Можно пояснить? Измениться только ссылка которую передаешь для скачивания или надо глобально что то менять. Можно привести пример ?

Comment: Разница в том, что вы можете получать структурированную информацию о статьях (список ссылок, wiki-text) вместо того, чтобы вручную парсить отрендеренную статью. Почитайте справку там много всего. Обратите внимание на метод `query`.

Comment: А оригинальная проблема, скорее всего, состоит в том, что на http:// запрос в ответ приходит перенаправление на https://, а не содержимое страницы.

Comment: @vp_arth А как на содержание страницы перенаправить запрос ? Я сейчас так пробую отправить запрос :http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Ключевая%20ставка%20в%20России . Что надо поменять чтоб работало ?

Comment: Там много параметров, [вот так](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exsentences=5&exsectionformat=plain&titles=Ключевая%20ставка%20в%20России&format=json), например

Comment: @vp_arth Мне нужна таблица только https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ключевая_ставка_в_России тут . Ключевой ставки, если есть предложения как её только спарсить , буду очень признателен.

Comment: [пример использования API (curl)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/811840/23044)

Comment: [пример кода для qt + json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/661079/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Минимально достаточный код для парсинга:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QSslError>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication application(argc, argv);
    QNetworkAccessManager qnam;
    const QNetworkRequest wikireq(QUrl(QStringLiteral("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=lemon")));
    QNetworkReply* wikirep = qnam.get(wikireq);
    QObject::connect(wikirep,&QNetworkReply::finished,[wikirep]()->void{
        QTextStream repStream(wikirep);
        qDebug() << "Response Received:\n" << repStream.readAll();
        wikirep->deleteLater();
    });
    QObject::connect(wikirep,QOverload<QNetworkReply::NetworkError>::of(&QNetworkReply::error),[wikirep]()->void{
        qDebug() << "Network Error:\n" << wikirep->errorString();
        wikirep->deleteLater();
    });
    QObject::connect(wikirep,&QNetworkReply::sslErrors,[wikirep](const QList<QSslError> &errors)->void{
        qDebug() << "SSL Errors:";
        for(auto&& err : errors)
            qDebug() << err.errorString();
        wikirep->deleteLater();
    });
    return application.exec();
}
```

Но на этом не всё, надо ещё выполнить указания по [ссылки](http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2009/11/solution-qsslsocket-cannot-call.html), если вы работаете в Windows. После чего скопировать две библиотеки(libeay32.dll,ssleay32.dll) из папки bin установленной программы и подключить их в pro файле `LIBS += -Llibeay32 -Lssleay32`