# Русский язык в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить поддержку русского языка в приложение QT. Пишу в Visual Studio (так как с QT Creator не разобрался, траблы с дебагером).

Нужно что бы можно было обьявить переменную и занести в нее русский текст:

```
QString var = "Привет!";
```

Пробовал такой код:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251"));
```

Если заношу текст в `QByteArray`, то все нормально, но я не могу с ним работать, мне далее нужно будет сравнивать строки. Если конвертирую в utf-8, то все равно кракозябра.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать.

Comment: А вы пробовали файлы исходного кода создавать с utf-8? (вне студии)

Comment: @free_ze Нет, а как это сделать?

Comment: Это умеет даже notepad, в диалоге сохранения в дропдауне ANSII замените на UTF-8.

Comment: @ free_ze То есть это можно сделать в любом текстовом редакторе да?

Comment: да, в любом удобном.

Comment: @free_ze И мне нужно все файли проэкта так сделать, чтобы русский поддерживался, или только те файлы где он используется?

Comment: Те, где вам нужны литералы в UTF. Можно поизвращаться, пытаясь конвертировать CP1251 в UTF. Но чаще всего такие проблемы никого не волнуют, ибо локализации хранят отдельно от исходников. Это особенность VS, с QtCreator таких проблем нет.

Comment: @free_ze Почему-то не получилось. Я сохранил файл так как вы сказали, но все равно символы не отображаются.

Comment: Рекомендую использовать Qt-ные возможности локализации. Тогда исходный код будет содержать строки только на английском языке, а их перевод будет храниться в отдельном файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должен работать вариант `QString::fromLocal8Bit()`, где локаль можно установить при помощи функции `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale()` и `QTextCodec::codecForName()`, передав в последнюю **Windows-1251**:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251"));
QString cyrillicName = QString::fromLocal8Bit("словоНаКириллице");
```

Обратите внимание на то, что `QString` использует `utf-16`, поэтому прямое копирование байтов в QString (например, через `QByteArray`) может давать не те результаты.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите прямо в исходном коде строку задать, то можно QStringLiteral макрос из qt5 применить:

```
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
  QString s {QStringLiteral(u"Привет!")};
  qDebug() << s;
}
```

Это использует Юникодные константы (`u""`), поэтому добавьте `CONFIG += c++11` в ваш `.pro` файл.

Это более эффективный код, так как не происходит ненужного копирования и конвертирования из одной кодировки в другую (`u""` это UTF-16 и QString внутри UTF-16 + [QStringLiteral magic](https://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html)).

Обратите внимание, что это никак не связано с кодировкой исходного кода (`input-charset`) и с кодировками, используемыми компилятором, для сохранения узких (`char`) и широких (`wchart_t`) строковых констант в исполняемом файле (`{,wide-}exec-charset`). Это также не имеет отношения к кодировкам используемых во внешних файлах или данных переданных по сети, итд -- суть в том что если данные у вас из другого источника, то решение специфичное для этого источника следует использовать (в разных контекстах, разные кодировки для текста могут быть).

`input-charset`, `exec-charset` это gcc имена. В VS это по другому настраивается [Does VC have a compile option like '-fexec-charset' in GCC to set the execution character set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23607830/4279). На  Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 CTP можно , `/utf-8` опцию попробовать, которая равнозначна `/source-charset:utf-8` плюс `/execution-charset:utf-8`, см. [Specification of source charset encoding in MSVC++, like gcc "-finput-charset=CharSet"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660712/4279).

Ваш код `QString var = "Привет!";` может работать, если вы выставите аналог  exec-charset в VS в utf-8 для qt5 (используется по умолчанию). `QString var = u8"Привет!";` будет работать даже без изменения `exec-charset` (исходный код может быть к примеру в `cp1251` и всё будет работать, если компилятор именно эту кодировку ожидает) -- во время компиляции такие строки в utf-8 превращают. Но так как в любом случае `QString` использует utf-16 внутри, то такой код занимается ненужными преобразованиями текста из одной кодировки в другую.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне этот вариант: QString var = u8"Привет!"; больше подошел.

Answer (score 0):

Просто сохраняйте исходники в utf8 и используйте

```
QString var = QString::fromUtf8("Привет!");
```

Не очень удобно, но работает.

Еще можно префикс u из c++11 применить, особенно если исходники не в utf8:

```
auto var = QString::fromUtf8(u"Привет!");
```