# Проблема с выводом кириллицы в консоль C++

Tags: c++, кодировка, консоль, codeblocks

В проекте исходные файлы в UTF8 кодировке, поменять нельзя, мне нужна именно эта кодировка. При попытке вывести в консоль русские буквы, получаю вот такое: 
[image: console1]

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
cout << "Файл открыт" << endl;

}
```

Много гуглил, пробовал всё, что предлагалось на форумах, такое как:

```
setlocale(0, "");

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

SetConsoleCP(866);
SetConsoleOutputCP(866);

SetConsoleCP(65001);
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);

locale current_locale("");
locale::global(current_locale);

SetConsoleOutputCP (CP_UTF8);

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
```

Ничего не помогло. Спасите меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [C++ вывод "галочки" на экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571405/23044)

Comment: Если отличается от кодировки по умолчанию, то [укажите компилятору кодировку исходного кода и желаемую кодировку строковых констант в исполняемом файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662138/23044)

Comment: К сожалению, это тоже не помогло. Проблема актуальна.

Comment: "не помогло" не очень информативно. Что конкретно вы пробовали, что ожидали получить, что вместо этого происходит (буквально) — какой код собирали, с какими опциями компилятора, в каком окружении запускали, приведите точный вывод. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте в настройках редактора:

```
settings/editor/global/encoding
```

кодировку UTF-8.

Смените шрифт окна (ПКМ по заголовку): *свойства/шрифт*, выберите *Lucida Console*.