# Как заменить заголовок консоли на Русский язык?

Tags: c++, windows, консоль

Использую такую конструкцию:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russia");
static const TCHAR* myTitle = TEXT("Генератор паролей [Тестовый]"); 
SetConsoleTitle(myTitle);
```

Пробовал записать так:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Но на выходе появляются крякозябры (пример на скриншоте):

[image: Крякозябры в заголовке]
Пробовал изменять: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russia");` на `setlocale(NULL, "Russia");` и т.п., но ничего не решало проблему.

Кодировку в консоли менял:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По-прежнему не получается получить Русский язык в заголовке программы :(

Единственное, что помогло (как-то решить проблему) - это:

```
system("Title Генератор паролей");
```

Но в самой консоли показывает строку "Администратор - Генератор паролей".

Comment: @Abyx, аргумент типа `"const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"`

Comment: работает ли `SetConsoleTitleW(L"\x043c\x0438\x0440")`?

Comment: @jfs, Да! =) Так работает) Спасибо, буду знать на будущее)

Comment: @jfs, Что за кодировка такая: `Мир` `(\x043c\x0438\x0440)` ?

Comment: чтобы не думать в какой кодировке вы исходный код сохраняете, чтобы не думать какую кодировку ваш компилятор с вашими настройками использует для чтения исходного кода, для сохранения строк в исполняемом файле (связанный вопрос: [Русский язык в Qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662138/23044)), можно символы используя их номера задавать (Unicode code point). К примеру: [U+043c это `М`](https://codepoints.net/U+043C).

Comment: @Abyx: вы уверены, что на Windows utf-8 файл не будет в рабочей code page интерпретирован (что к кракозябрам ведёт)? К примеру, [у VS есть /utf-8 параметр](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660712/specification-of-source-charset-encoding-in-msvc-like-gcc-finput-charset-ch)

Comment: В целом, при работе с текстом лучше использовать Unicode вместо костылей таких как  setlocale, SetConsoleCP, SetConsoleOutputCP. К примеру, для вывода текста в консоль попробуйте решение из [C++ вывод "галочки" на экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571428/23044)

Comment: @Abyx: это не адресует вопрос о кодировке исходного кода (компилятор не телепат -- он не знает какую вы кодировку указали, и наличие параметров таких как /utf-8 указывает, что utf-8 не является кодировкой по умолчанию)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу на картинке библиотеки `<locale>`. Хотя, как без неё не возникает ошибка на `setlocal`?

Запустил ваш код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>


int main()
{
    wchar_t const * myTitle{L"Генератор паролей [Тестовый]"};
    ::SetConsoleTitleW(myTitle);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ещё помогла [Эта статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164193/)

Comment: @GooliveR ссылка ведёт на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Поправил ссылку

Comment: Не знаю, у меня ошибка не возникает при использование `setlocal` - без библиотеки `#include <locale>` =) Магия)

Comment: @GooliveR очень странно)

Comment: `setlocale` тут ни к чему, тем более, что используется не правильно